# Cannot Compare JSON files

Tags: python, json

Here is my code,

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import urllib, json
import requests

url = requests.get('http://elbekjk.com/ids.json')
ids = url

root = Tk()
root.title('Data Discovery Lab')
root.iconbitmap('c://DataDiscoveryLab/images/datadiscoverylab_favicon_142c61.ico')
root.geometry('300x450')
root.resizable(False, False)

myblue = "#142c61"
white = '#ffffff'
root.configure(background = myblue)
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
canvas = Canvas(frame, bg=myblue, width=300, height=450)
canvas.pack()
logo = PhotoImage(file='c://DataDiscoveryLab/images/datadiscoverylab-logo-white-on-transparent-116.png')
canvas.create_image(150,120,image=logo)

username_label = ttk.Label(root, text="Username:")
username_label.place(relx = .2, rely = .5, anchor = CENTER)
username_entry = ttk.Entry(root)
username_entry.place(relx = .6, rely = .5, anchor = CENTER)
password_label = ttk.Label(root, text="Password:")
password_label.place(relx = .2, rely = .6, anchor = CENTER)
password_entry = ttk.Entry(root,  show="*")
password_entry.place(relx = .6, rely = .6, anchor = CENTER)

username_entry = username_entry.get()
password_entry = password_entry.get()

def check_id():
    id_dict = {"username": username_entry, "password": password_entry}  # create dictionary with entered username and password
    id_str = json.dumps(id_dict)  # convert dictionary to a JSON-formatted string
    if id_str in ids:
        print('ID found')
    else:
        print('ID not found')

login_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Login", command=check_id)
login_button.place(relx = .68, rely = .7, anchor = CENTER)

root.mainloop()
```

This code is a simple GUI application that creates a login screen using the Tkinter library. The purpose of this code is to allow users to enter their login credentials (username and password) and check if they exist in a list of IDs stored in a JSON file.

The code first imports the required libraries, including tkinter, ttk, and PIL. It then makes an HTTP request to a URL that returns a JSON file containing a list of IDs. The IDs are stored in the variable "ids".

The code then creates a GUI window using Tkinter and sets the window's properties, such as its title, icon, size, and background color. It also creates a canvas and displays an image on it.

The code creates two input fields for the username and password using ttk.Entry() and ttk.Label(). It also creates a login button that calls the function "check_id()" when clicked. The check_id() function checks if the entered username and password exist in the list of IDs retrieved earlier.

If the entered ID exists in the list, the code prints "ID found," and if it does not exist, the code prints "ID not found."

Finally, the code enters the main event loop using root.mainloop() to keep the GUI window open and respond to user actions until the user closes the window.

Comment: you are dumping the input data as a json string, I would do it the other way around and json.loads() the response file into a python object

Comment: You cannot compare the string representation of json data as string data.  The same values can generate different json strings, while still representing the same data.  You should read your json data file as a dictionary and simply search for your id and password within the dictionary, not compare them as string data.

Comment: This is not a good design (comparing JSON-s as string), but technically `ids = url.text` may fix it. `requests.get()` gives you a `Request` object. https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content - side note: you would have noticed it if ever tried a `print(ids)`, `print()`-ing everything everywhere is a simple, but viable way of finding problems.